# How to paginate Trello api response?

Tags: trello

I am using Trello's API to pull the boards and their cards.

I've noticed one of the boards I am pulling is approaching thousand cards at the moment, so I wonder how to paginate the results?

I tried using the `since` attribute and feed last card's update time into it, but afterwards I get zero results, so I must be doing somethign wrong.

The api documentation doesn't say much and the API response I've tried is very confusing:

> /boards/xyz/cards?limit=1&before=2015-1-1

returns card which activity is *after* specified date.

> "dateLastActivity"=>"2015-02-03T17:51:23.253Z",

and there is no other date field I could use to continue pagination.

Comment: Read this **before** ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You must provide your working example. I think that you need to paginate by yourself, the API returns you all values. The `since` attribute I can't found it. I found `filter` in cards and lists, but is for another task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

​You are right in your assessment. The **before** and **since** parameters operate on card creation date. Because we use standard Mongo IDs, you can actually derive the Card creation date from the Card ID. (Here is one such tool: https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/)

​
​As a convenience, Trello also allows you to pass in a Card ID to the **before** and *since* parameters and we will use the date for you. The recommended way of paging through a large set of cards is to repeat the same query, and use these parameters to move forward or backward.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. Now if you could also document it in your documentation for others, that would be awesome :)

Comment: I just tried it with single card's id as an argument for both before and then after and the response was really werd. Both before and after returned different cards, but they also shared one card (which wasn't the card that was the parameter). 

I've emailed the support, but maybe you could write up a real documentation so that everyone can benefit.

Answer (score 6):

So since the API really desn't work as you'd expect it to, I am documenting this here at least.

I created a testing board with cards `A`, `B`, `C`, ... , `M` so I can test on it.

First, grabbing all cards works as expected.

> api.find(:boards, '56af532ae7a74a5fcac32e66').cards.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [
 ["A", "56af53367f15b163c0e345fd"],
 ["B", "56af533783d4fccc1cce3941"],
 ["C", "56af533831727db409451c9e"],
 ["D", "56af53397bf672bb56c7c536"],
 ["E", "56af5339f5e67cf6bcc7323b"],
 ["F", "56af533ac0aa02de54ab881a"],
 ["G", "56af533b212b095266ebb506"],
 ["H", "56af533e11992f20f375fca1"],
 ["I", "56af533fc1775129aaa7028b"],
 ["J", "56af5345f81227a7a1cc3a35"],
 ["K", "56af5345e36b3d3c45b16967"],
 ["L", "56af534d964b6c4aa93d4aca"],
 ["M", "56af534e768610ff67c781ce"]
]
```

Note: the order of the cards isn't by create time, its by their appearance in the board from left column to right column and from top to bottom.

## Limit

Okay, time to start paginating. Let's get only the first card, shall we?

> board.cards(limit: 1).map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [["M", "56af534e768610ff67c781ce"]]
```

Ooops, API returns the last element. Definitely unexpected. Lets play with the after/before next.

## Before

Let's grab card before the last one.

> board.cards(limit: 1, before: '56af534e768610ff67c781ce').map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [["L", "56af534d964b6c4aa93d4aca"]]
```

That works well, `L` is before `M`.

## After

What happens if we grab a card after the last one, response should be empty, right?

> board.cards(limit: 1, after: '56af534e768610ff67c781ce').map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [["M", "56af534e768610ff67c781ce"]]
```

Mmmm, what? What happens if I grab two card then?

> board.cards(limit: 2, after: '56af534e768610ff67c781ce').map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [
  ["L", "56af534d964b6c4aa93d4aca"], 
  ["M", "56af534e768610ff67c781ce"]
]
```

This defies any logic. Definitely can't go through the list from start to finish then, because there is no end to the card list.

## Back to pagination

We'll have to go through the cards in reverse order in that case. Just specifying `limit` works, since by default we're going in reverse order. (which makes total sense, right?)

> api.find(:boards, '56af532ae7a74a5fcac32e66').cards(limit: 5).map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [
 ["I", "56af533fc1775129aaa7028b"], 
 ["J", "56af5345f81227a7a1cc3a35"], 
 ["K", "56af5345e36b3d3c45b16967"], 
 ["L", "56af534d964b6c4aa93d4aca"], 
 ["M", "56af534e768610ff67c781ce"]
]
```

Don't let the order of these items fool you! Its still the order how they *appear* in the board, they're not sorted by the time of creation. If I move `M` card in its column so that it is right over `L`, the API will return them in reverse order.

The question is now, how to grab the older card from the list? As the other answer says, the IDs are timestamp, so we just sort by the ID and pick the lowest one and continue paginating.

Note: If you're fast, you can create multiple cards during the same second, so the IDs may not in the right order as they just use the number of seconds, not microseconds. That doesn't prevent us from paginating though.

> board.cards(limit: 5, before: '56af533fc1775129aaa7028b').map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [
  ["D", "56af53397bf672bb56c7c536"], 
  ["E", "56af5339f5e67cf6bcc7323b"], 
  ["F", "56af533ac0aa02de54ab881a"], 
  ["G", "56af533b212b095266ebb506"], 
  ["H", "56af533e11992f20f375fca1"]
]
```

Awesome, we're getting the next page, let's get the last one.

> board.cards(limit: 5, before: '56af53397bf672bb56c7c536').map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }

```
=> [
  ["A", "56af53367f15b163c0e345fd"],
  ["B", "56af533783d4fccc1cce3941"],
  ["C", "56af533831727db409451c9e"]
]
```

Yesss, so the last page contains less cards, than the limit, so we know its the last page. Horray! (if it was equal to page size, we'd find the next response is empty)

Comment: This works for a small set, but there is a 1000 limit on actions. If you limit to, say, 500, then page=0 is fine, page=1 is fine... but page=2 will throw an error saying you requested 1500 and the limit is 1000. This means you need to page by since/before pairs/ranges. This is entirely counter-intuitive on how pagination works.

Comment: Did you mean to reply to this answer? I don't use pagination at all, and use since/before in it.

Comment: I misread the last snippet, my mistake - didn't notice you change the before Trello ID. You are right in that you have to process them "backwards" using before. The way I solved this was using before and since together. So I'd keep "since" as nil to start with and then store "since= 56af533e11992f20f375fca1" (H) after the run.  On the next pass, I'd do use that "watermark" for since as well as the "before" approach you outline above for pagination.